# Was the "a" glyph ever used for ajV in Hittite?

Tags: orthography, sound-change, hittite, cuneiform, akkadian

As fdb mentioned in [a comment](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/33878/were-long-vowels-distinguished-in-cuneiform#comment73896_33880):

> The sequence a-a is a scribal convention for ajV [in Akkadian]. Some Assyriologists treat it as a single sign with the “Lautwert” aju, aji, aja

In Hittite, Kloekhorst postulates a sound change *aiV > āV, to explain forms like *pa-a-un* "I went" and *pa-a-er* "they went" from **pai-un* and **pai-er*. He also proposes that this verb had two stems *pai-* and *paii-*, with the second necessary to explain forms like *pa-a-iz-zi* < *pāizzi* < **paii-zzi* where the *i* remains visible. (In his analysis, *j* isn't phonemic in Hittite, but is an allophone of *i* before a vowel.)

This does seem like an entirely plausible sound change, but the two separate stems do feel a bit ad-hoc, which made me curious—is there any evidence for plene *a* being used for a sequence *ajV* in Hittite, as an alternative to this being a diachronic sound change?

Comment: For curiosities sake, if the answer were positive, which form would you read differently and how, conjecturally speaking? Kloekhorst proposes the enlarged root contained a cognate to Lat. *eo* (e.g. in *comeo*), which is not a mere sound change; this further implies the bare root gave a Place Word as stem with inflection, correct?

Comment: @vectory If _a_ could be read as _ajV_, then _pa-a-un_, _pa-a-er_, _pa-a-iz-zi_ could be read as _pājun_, _pājer_, _pāizzi_, with the same stem _pai-_ in all the forms.

Comment: Note German *pfui* for comparison, though often compared with Latin *fi* and explained as onomatopoetic (cp. likewise *to fart*, *piss*). It does in fact mean "leave it, go away" when used as such in commands to children, cp. *i-bah!*. The diphtong also resounding in Swedish *fy* should be of interest. I still don't see clearly through Kloekhorst's derivation, nor what you had in mind, so I'll just leave this, here, as pure speculation.